# Konva - clear layer but keep the background

Tags: javascript, konvajs

Im trying to clear the layer from every circle and line (remove it completely) but keep the image in the background.

If I use `layer.clear()` it removes the image also.

**Question**: How to clear the layer but avoid removing the image?

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-night-t4vtt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`layer.clear()` do not remove objects from the scene. It is just clear canvas element and on the next `layer.draw()` all objects will be drawn again.

Instead of `layer.clear()` you need to remove objects, that you don't need anymore. From the demo, I see that you need to remove lines and circles.  You can use `layer.find(selector)` to find that nodes and destroy them.

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  layer.find('Line').destroy();
  layer.find('Circle').destroy();
  layer.draw();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I just did a little workaround. I used `layer.removeChildren` and somehow it works fine. Is it better approach? Or I should use yours?